# How can I know which projection code a layer is using?

Tags: openlayers-3

I've spent a lot of time realizing [this](http://jsbin.com/tejecuqiza/edit?js,output):

```
var view = new ol.View({

    //this doesn't work
    //center: [-73.979681,40.7033127],

    //this works
    center: ol.proj.transform([-73.979681,40.7033127], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),

    zoom: 8
});
```

I've found on [OpenLayer's quickstart](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/doc/quickstart.html) how to transform a projection from one to another. However, that isn't very clear on another tutorials. I'm not used to those specific projection codes, neither which layer uses which.

Is there a list where I can know which projection code a layer uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when no projection is specified in the options passed to the `ol.View` constructor, the view projection is Web Mercator (whose EPSG code is `EPSG:3857`).

You can do `map.getView().getProjection()` to get the view projection. And you call `getCode` on the returned projection object to get its code.

To transform coordinates from lon/lat to Web Mercator you need to use the following:

```js
 var coords = ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

OpenLayers v3.5.0, due next week, will make this a bit more convenient, with a `fromLonLat` function.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did to transform from lon/lat to Web Mercator. I'm glad to know that function is going to be added. OpenLayers ia easy to setup, however, adding markers and styling them are still PAINFUL!